# Can R recognize the type of distribution used as a function argument?

Tags: r, function, random

## Background

I have a simple function called `TBT`. This function has a single argument called `x`. A user can provide any type `rdistribution_name()` (e.g., `rnorm()`, `rf()`, `rt()`, `rbinom()` etc.) existing in R for argument `x`, **EXCEPT ONE:** "`rcauchy()`".

## Question

I was wondering how R could recognize that a user has provided an `rcauchy()` as the input for `x`, and when this is the case, then R issues a warning message?

**Here is my R code with no success:**

```
TBT = function(x) {

if( x == rcauchy(...) ) { warning("\n\tThis type of distribution is not supported.") }

}

TBT( x = rcauchy(1e4) )
```

`Error in TBT(rcauchy(10000)) : '...' used in an incorrect context`

Comment: did you try: `gauchy.test()`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/goft/versions/1.3.1/topics/cauchy.test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expeciting them do call to random function when they call your function, you could so

```
TBT <- function(x) {
    xcall <- match.call()$x
    if (class(xcall)=="call" && xcall[[1]]=="rcauchy") { 
        warning("\n\tThis type of distribution is not supported.") 
    }
}
TBT( x = rcauchy(1e4) )
```

But this would not catch cases like

```
x <- rcauchy(1e4)
TBT( x )
```

R can't track where the data in the `x` variable came from